# Understanding nested list comprehension

Tags: python, nested, list-comprehension

I want to understand nested list comprehension.
Below, I listed a list comprehension expression and their for loop equivalent.
I wonder if my understanding is correct on those.

For example,

```
[(min([row[i] for row in rows]),max([row[i] for row in rows])) 
for i in range(len(rows[0]))]
```

is equivalent to

```
result=[]
for i in range(len(rows[0])):
  innerResult=[]
  for row in rows:
    innerResult.append(row[i])
  innerResult2=[]
  for row in rows:
    innerResult2.append(row[i])
  tuple=(min(innerResult), max(innerResult2))
  result.append(tuple)
```

If I may generalize, I guess

```
[exp2([exp1 for x in xSet]) for y in ySet]
```

form can be translated to the following. (I hope I'm correct on this)

```
result=[]
for y in ySet:
  innerResult =[]
  for x in xSet:
    innerResult.append(exp1)
  exp2Result = exp2(innerResult)
  result.append(exp2Result)
```

For simpler case,

```
[exp1 for x in xSet for y in ySet]
```

is equal to

```
result=[] 
for x in xSet:
  for y in ySet: 
    result.append(exp1)
```

whereas,

```
[[exp1 for x in xSet] for y in ySet]
```

is equal to

```
result=[]
for y in ySet:
  innerResult=[]
  for x in xSet:
    innerResult.append(exp1)
  result.append(innerResult)
```

I asked a similar question on [Equivalent for loop expression for complex list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047965/equivalent-for-loop-expression-for-complex-list-comprehension)
The answers given there reconstruct the form after understanding what it does internally.
I'd like to know how it works systematically so I can apply the concept to other slightly varying examples.

Comment: Side note: In your example, you could have [transposed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) the rows into columns using `cols = zip(*rows)`, after which you could have simply used `min(col)` and `max(col)` for each column: `[(min(c), max(c)) for c in cols]`. Or in one short line: `[(min(c), max(c)) for col in zip(*rows)]`.

Comment: Would it be true, and improve clarity, if you were to write exp1(x,y) instead of just exp1 ?    I _think_ it's implied, but would like to be sure?

Comment: @GreenAsJade well, yes that would work, exp1 was meant to be expression1

Comment: "Here's a detailed mental model; is my understanding correct?" generally doesn't make a good question, because it's mostly shoving the answer (or an attempt at one) into the question.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The short answer is: **yes, you are correct in your understanding**.

There's only a catch: the way you normally use nested list comprehension in python code is to operate on multidimensional arrays.

A typical example is when you operate on matrices:

```
>>> matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> [[el - 1 for el in row] for row in matrix]
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

As you can see the "nesting" works by operating on each dimension of the matrix.

In the examples you provided, it seems that `ySet` [unfortunate name btw, as *[sets](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)* are one of the types provided with python] is just a generic counter, which makes a bit harder to follow what is going on under the hood.

As for your first example:

```
>>> rows = ([1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30])
>>> [(min([row[i] for row in rows]),max([row[i] for row in rows])) for i in range(len(rows[0]))]
[(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30)]
```

You might wish to look into the [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) built-in function:

```
>>> zip(rows[0], rows[1])
[(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30)]
```

or for maximum brevity and elegance:

```
>>> zip(*rows)
[(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30)]
```

HTH!

Answer (score 78):

Indeed, you are correct. This is described in detail in the [Expressions section in the Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#list-displays).

Note especially the order of nesting of several `for`s in a single list comprehension, which is always left-to-right:

```
>>> matrix = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> [item for item in row for row in matrix] # oops!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    [item for item in row for row in matrix]
NameError: name 'row' is not defined
>>> [item for row in matrix for item in row] # nesting is in left-to-right order
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I've looked at the link. Indeed, there's an explanation for [item for row in matrix for item in row] but couldn't find explanation for [[exp for item in row] for row in matrix] format. Am I missing something from the grammar listed there?

Comment: You're not missing anything, but that's because your example doesn't use any more special grammar, it is just two simple list comprehensions! The first `[exp for item in row]` will create a list given a row. The "outer" list comprehension will create a list, in which each item is a list created by the "inner" list-comp, one for each row in the matrix.

Comment: Oh. As you pointed out in your answer, the order is important. And, I was wondering if there's a section on library reference which talks about ordering of [[list comprehension] list comprehension] format.

Comment: There in no such section in the docs that I know of. The reason is that in a list comprehension, the expression evaluated for each item can be any valid Python expression. In this context, an "inner" list comprehension is just like any other Python expression.

Comment: wow whee.. am I the only one surprised by this ordering: now an explanation why the macro level (matrix in this case..) occurs before the nested/micro level (row level..) might be in order..

Comment: @javadba If I remember correctly, the reasoning is that it is like the order of nested for loops in code.

Comment: That actually helps .. Guido's thinking is  typically somewhere between 90 to 180 degrees to mine: no exception here.