# Using nested generator expression in Python 2.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In an appengine application, I want to build a set of all property names for a list of objects.
This should be fairly straightforward:

```
users = security.User.all().fetch(1000)
props = set([k for k in u.properties().keys() for u in users])
```

However, the code above results in an error:

```
File "/Users/paulkorzhyk/Projects/appengine-flask-template/app/app.py", line 70, in allusers
props = set([k for k in u.properties().keys() for u in users])
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'u' referenced before assignment
```

After some experiments in the debugger I've noticed that adding a dummy expression fixes the code:

```
users = security.User.all().fetch(1000)
[u.properties().keys() for u in users]
props = set([k for k in u.properties().keys() for u in users])
```

This is quite counter-intuitive to me, why is original version failing in Python 2.7? and why adding a 'useless' expression in the middle fixes the problem?

Comment: As per this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049798/understanding-nested-list-comprehension the association should be left to right and hence reordering the loop statements should rectify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change the order of evaluation

```
props = set([k for k in u.properties().keys() for u in users])
```

to

```
props = set([k for u in users for k in u.properties().keys() ])
```

also you don't need a list comprehension but generator expression with a set comprehension would work here

```
props = set(k for u in users for k in u.properties().keys() )
```

Order of evaluation is from right to left

In your original expression

```
set([k for k in u.properties().keys() for u in users])
```

can be broken as

```
for k in u.properties().keys(): # Here u is undefined
    for u in users:
        #what ever
```

The interesting phenomena of using a Dummy expression is the fact that List Comprehension Leaks Variables, which causes `u` to be leaked in the global scope

So

```
[u.properties().keys() for u in users]
```

leaks `u` in global scope,

which makes

```
set([k for k in u.properties().keys() for u in users])
```

legitimate

The following example shows, how list comprehension leaks variables

```
>>> del i
>>> foo = [range(1,10) for _ in range(10)]
>>> globals()['i']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#84>", line 1, in <module>
    globals()['i']
KeyError: 'i'
>>> [i for i in foo]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
>>> globals()['i']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, really helpful. Is this leaking of variables a bug?

Comment: This is not a Bug but a Feature post Python 2.3. This feature has been removed from Python 3.0. Refer http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#id20

Answer (score 1):

The reason your original example fails is that you have the `for` clauses in the wrong order.  The `for` clauses in list/generator comprehensions are in the same order they would be if you wrote the code out as nested for loops.  That is, the leftmost one is the outermost, the rightmost is the innermost.  Switch the order of the `for` clauses to make it work.

The reason the dummy expression changes the behavior is that the dummy expression is a list comprehension, and in Python 2, list comprehensions (unlike generator comprehensions) leak their loop variable to the enclosing scope.  The leaked `u` allows your second example to run, but it isn't doing what you think it is, because your `for` clauses in the `props = ...` line are still in the wrong order.  It's only looping over one value of `u`, namely the last `u` value from the dummy expression.