# python nested list comprehensions

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I am learning python and going through their tutorials. I understand list comprehensions and nested lists comprehensions. With the following code, though, I am trying to understand the order of events.

```
>>> matrix = [
...[1, 2, 3, 4],
...[5, 6, 7, 8],
...[9, 10, 11, 12],
... ]
>>> [[row[i] for row in matrix] for i in range(4)]
[[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4,8,12]]
```

According to the nested list comprehension, is the first "i" and the second "i" the same variable and do they both increase at the same time? I guess I don't understand how the resulting big list goes from the first sublist [1, 5, 9] to the second sublist [2, 6, 10]

Comment: Just for fun, note that you can produce these results with [`zip(*matrix)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[row[i] for row in matrix] for i in range(4)]
```

is equivalent to

```
my_list = []
for i in range(4):
    my_list_2 = []
    for row in matrix:
        my_list_2.append(row[i])
    my_list.append(my_list_2)
```

> is the first "i" and the second "i" the same variable and do they both increase at the same time?

Of course, it is. If it was not the same `i`, the code would throw an error because one of the two would not be defined.

You may be interested in this question: [Understanding nested list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049798/understanding-nested-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 0):

I made a function in order to do it automatically (sorry for the example, i took it from someone) :

Let's say, you have this example :

```
# 2-D List 
matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]] 
  
flatten_matrix = [] 
  
for sublist in matrix: 
    for val in sublist: 
        flatten_matrix.append(val)
```

This is my function :
(first, turn the example into a string that you will send to the function)

```
x = "for sublist in matrix:for val in sublist:flatten_matrix.append(val)"
```

then the function :

```
def ComprenhensionizeList(nested_for_loop_str):

    splitted_fors = nested_for_loop_str.split(':')
    lowest_val = splitted_fors[1].split(' ')[1]
    comprehensionizer = '[ '+ lowest_val+' '+splitted_fors[0]+' '+splitted_fors[1]+' ]'
    print(comprehensionizer)
```

and the output :

```
[ val for sublist in matrix for val in sublist ]
```