# Python: filtering in nested list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

For example I have the following list of lists:

```
 matrix = [['.', 'W', '.'], 
           ['.', 'W', '.'],
           ['W', '.', '.']]
```

I want to have a list with all rows, column indexes.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python) they show how to do it for a  single list.

However I want to do it for nested list. There are more then one examples of this like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125128/python-nested-list-comprehensions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists?page=1&tab=active#tab-top)

So this works for me:

```
l = [[(i,j) for j,el in enumerate(row) if el == 'W'] for i,row in enumerate(matrix)]
flat_list = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

>> [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
```

However how would I do this with one list comprehension statement?

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: @PaulRoub maybe I asked the question wrong. I was looking for the answer from zipa. I didn't understand the syntax of list comprehension enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than doing it in one line:

```
[(i, j) for i, row in enumerate(matrix) for j, el in enumerate(row) if el == 'W']
#[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
```

You can also use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
list(zip(*np.where(np.array(matrix)=='W')))
#[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand the syntax of list comprehension enough. I ran it with %%timeit and the list comprehension was 1.36 µs ± 7.2 ns per loop vs 4.55 µs ± 12.9 ns per loop with numpy.