# Converting Numbers to Words

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list of strings from which I want to convert numbers into text equivalents. eg. 2 to two

This is what *result* looks like:

```
[
    ['nn', 'known', 'tsutsumi', 'father', 'yasujiro', 'sow', 'seed', 'family', 'dominion'],
    ['un', 'secretari', 'gener', 'kofi', 'annan', 'appoint', 'special', 'repres', 'iraq', 'help', 'improv', 'commun', 'iraqi', 'leader'],
    ['year', '2016']
]
```

Here is my code:

```
from num2words import num2words

result=[]
with open("./Stemmingg.txt") as filer:
    for line in filer:
        result.append(line.strip().split())

temp=[]

for item in result:
    r=num2words(item)
    temp.append(r)
```

However, this gives me an error which says:

```
TypeError: type(['nn', 'known', 'tsutsumi', 'father', 'yasujiro', 'sow', 'seed', 'family', 'dominion']) not in [long, int, float]
```

Comment: I don't see any numbers in the `result` you provided...

Comment: And is your input always a list of lists, or can list items be just a simple string as well?

Comment: @Will: There are some numbers in the entire *result*, I just put some examples to show what *result* looks like. The input is always a list of list.

Comment: `result` is a list of lists. I don't know how the api works but my guess is you want `result.extend(line.strip().split())`.

Comment: see error message - `num2words` expects only numbers `long`, `int`, `float`

Comment: So could I add in an if-else for it to detect if a number, then perform num2words else skip?

Comment: It looks like the API raises an exception, so do a try/except block.

Comment: @CoderQueen ok cool, check my answer. This should work for actual `int`s/`float`s or numeric-strings like `"22"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly try to create a list `result` that is flattened i.e. no nested list inside it if any. Then use evaluation of the list item if it is number (`int` or `long` using `isdigit()` function) and use `literal_eval` before passing to the function `num2words` since `num2words` expects `int` not `str` .

```
from num2words import num2words
from ast import literal_eval

result = []
with open("/Users/mr/Documents/Stemmingg.txt",'r') as filer:
    for line in filer:
        lst = line.strip().split()#split every line by spaces
        for item in lst:
            result.append(item.strip())#creating flattened list by appending item one by one

temp=[]     
for item in result:
    if item.isdigit():#check if int of long but not float
        r=num2words(literal_eval(item))#using literal_eval to convert string to number
        temp.append(r)
    else:
        pass
print temp
```

**N.B.If you want to keep every other words then change**

This

```
else:
       pass
```

To

```
else:
      temp.append(item)
```

Comment: This isn't giving me any output. It isn't printing *tmp* also. Just hangs.

Comment: I still do not receive any output. Here is what the file looks like: 

*fall demand oil asia help cut averag price gallon regular gasolin unit state* *$1.08 $1.20 last month*
*specif address dozen protest*
*part tell asian turmoil affect european economi*
*take 90 day*

They are all different sentences.

Comment: The you need all number in the file like `*$1.08 $1.20` and `90 ` to be converted into spelling?

Comment: Not the floats. Just the integers. It ran now but what I am receiving by printing first few *temp* : [u'three', u'zero', u'one', u'nine', u'nine', u'zero', u'one', u'zero', u'eight', u'one'] 
It seems to have kept only the converted text and removed every other word.

Comment: OK edited and checked finally- now check. Now it keeps every other words

Answer (score 2):

You have a `list` of `list`s, not a list of `str`s. This would be a naive approach:

```
from num2words import num2words
result=[]
with open("/Users/mr/Documents/Stemmingg.txt") as filer:
    for line in filer:
        result.append(line.strip().split())

result = [[
    num2words(subitem) if isinstance(subitem, (int, float, long)) else subitem for subitem in item
] for item in result]
```

This is a *nested list comprehension*; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8050243/145279) for more information about how those work.

Now, this still has a problem! If I have the *string* `'22'`, our [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) check fails! So we might need some additional logic, with the help of [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
def digitsToWords(item):
    if isinstance(item, (int, float, long)):
        return num2words(item)

    if isinstance(item, (str, unicode)):
        if item.isdigit():
            return num2words(int(item))

        if item.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit():
            return num2words(float(item))

    return item

result = [[digitsToWords(subitem) for subitem in item] for item in result]
```

If you don't want to convert `float`s to words, do this instead:

```
def digitsToWords(item):
    if isinstance(item, (int, long)):
        return num2words(item)

    if isinstance(item, (str, unicode)) and item.isdigit():
        return num2words(int(item))

    return item

result = [[digitsToWords(subitem) for subitem in item] for item in result]
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason for that specific error is because your array of results is actually an array of arrays.

So saying something like

```
for item in result:
    r=num2words(item)
```

item will actually be

`['nn', 'known', 'tsutsumi', 'father', 'yasujiro', 'sow', 'seed', 'family', 'dominion']`

Your options for that are either to flatten it into a single dimensional array or to have a nested for loop, like so (or use a nested list comprehension, as answered above):

```
for arr in result:
    for item in arr: 
        r=num2words(item)
```

However, you still have a problem--num2words must take a number.  None of your items are actually numbers (they're all strings).  Since you're parsing from a file, you should probably try to cast to an int, and only convert it if it works.  So the code would look something like:

```
from num2words import num2words
result=[]
with open("/Users/mr/Documents/Stemmingg.txt") as filer:
    for line in filer:
        result.append(line.strip().split())

temp=[]
for arr in result:
    for item in arr: 
        try:
            r=num2words(int(item))
            temp.append(r)
        except:
            pass
```