# Python List Comprehensions Adding integer in to diffrent list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, list-comprehension

I am faced issue with a list comprehension missing value in a result list. I have two lists. when i am trying with for loop. value is expected as i want to like(7 4 2 -1 0) but i don't need integer values in need list. when use list comprehension i got only 4 value [4, 2, -1, 0]. i don't understand what happens in my logic. if there is anyone you help me kindly see a code.

```
l1 = [3, 6, 9, 2, 11, 14, 13]
f = [7]
```

subtraction l1 last element to l1 nth element.
I am trying this formula(pls see code more understandable):

```
l2 = l1[-1]-l1[n]
```

and after that, i am trying to put if else condition in like this:

```
if l2 <= f:
        print(l3)
```

this is the code I am trying in for loop

```
In [230]: for l2 in l1:
 ...:     l3 = l1[-1]-l2
 ...:     #print(l3)
 ...:     for f1 in f:
 ...:         if l3<=f1:
 ...:             print(l3)
 ...:             
 ...:         
7
4
2
-1
0
```

And for the List Comprehension code is:

```
  for f1 in f:
      f1

In [47]: l1 = [x[-1] - l for l in x if l >= int(f1)]
...: 

In [48]: l1
Out[48]: [4, 2, -1, 0]
```

Comment: Please format code as code. / [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). / Avoid spelling mistakes please.

Comment: @user202729 wait

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049798/understanding-nested-list-comprehension

Comment: Are you aware of `l1[-1]` being always the last element of `l1` ?

Comment: @Joe yep in my case l1[-1] = 13

Comment: The list comprehension you showed does not do the same thing as the `for` loop. First of all what's `x`? The main thing is that you're not checking the same condition (`<=` vs `>=`) and the value being tested is not the same (`l3 <= f1` vs `l >= int(f1)`). Try the following: `[l1[-1] - l for l in l1 if (l1[-1] - l) <= int(f1)]`. **Edit**: A more equivalent translation of your loop: `[l1[-1] - l for l in l1 if any((l1[-1] - l) <= f0 for f0 in f)]`

Comment: @pault ogic is correct I spent whole day on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list comprehension does not match with your `for` loop.
You must replace:

```
[x[-1] - l for l in x if l >= int(f1)]
```

with:

```
[(l1[-1] - l) for l in l1 if (l1[-1] - l) <= int(f1)]
```

which gives the expected output.

(I added parentheses for better readability)

Comment: Yep, although OP may disagree based on the comments.