# Nested List Comprehensions Example

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension, nested-loops

### Problem

I have next list:

```
a = (('_a_1', '_a_2'), [0.3, 0.6]) 
b = (('_a_3', '_a_4'), [0.15, 0.56]) 
c = (('_a_5', '_a_6'), [0.22, 0.6])

l = [a, b, c]
```

What I wan't: choose first tuples of list and remove `_a_` labels.
Result:

```
[['1','2'],['3','4'],['5','6']]
```

---

### What I tried

I know I can do it using **list comprehension**. But I can't comprehend it :D
What I'm trying:

```
[ el.replace('_a_','') for m in l for el in m[0]]
```

result:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

I think it is closed to right solution. Just add something like:

```
[ [el.replace('_a_','') for m in l] for el in m[0]]
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: Can you explain what your comprehensions are doing in words? That would help you clarify more than adding random brackets here and there

Comment: @MadPhysicist I want to put inner loop into list `[]`.

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam The code you posted claiming to sort-of-work actually does not. It throws `NameError: name 'm' is not defined`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounisyou are right! Copied from the wrong place! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
a = (('_a_1', '_a_2'), [0.3, 0.6]) 
b = (('_a_3', '_a_4'), [0.15, 0.56]) 
c = (('_a_5', '_a_6'), [0.22, 0.6])

l = [a, b, c]

[ [el.replace('_a_','') for el in tup[0]] for tup in l]
# [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]
```

Comment: Does it mean, If I add inner brackets I must `inverse` logic: In usual nested loops every inner loop adds at the end, but here inner loop added at the left?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using `str.split`:

```
a = (('_a_1', '_a_2'), [0.3, 0.6]) 
b = (('_a_3', '_a_4'), [0.15, 0.56]) 
c = (('_a_5', '_a_6'), [0.22, 0.6])

res = [[i.split('_')[-1], j.split('_')[-1]] for (i, j), k in [a, b, c]]

# [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]
```

You can also use `str.replace`:

```
res = [[i.replace('_a_', ''), j.replace('_a_', '')] for (i, j), k in [a, b, c]]
```

As suggested by @Ev.Kounis, you can also write this functionally:

```
res = [list(map(lambda x: x.rsplit('_', 1)[-1], k)) for k, _ in [a, b, c]]
```

Nested list comprehensions [require specific ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049798/understanding-nested-list-comprehension), intuitive to some but not to others. The above solutions avoid them altogether.

Comment: or `[list(map(lambda x: x.rsplit('_', 1)[-1], k)) for k, _ in [a, b, c]]` which might be slightly faster. Nevertheless, +1

Comment: fyi, the solution using `map` is more than two times slower.

Comment: @Arne, I'm not surprised, but thank you for noting. I guess it's good to see different ways while you're learning.

Answer (score 0):

```
res=[[j.replace("_a_","") for j in i[0]]  for i in l]
#OUT
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: code seems self explanatory, nothing much complicated otherwise putted the explanation :)

Comment: Well, you can explain why the original attempt failed and how your code fixed the issue. SO is no for sharing working code, but learning why something is not working! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it would be to use the `zip` function:

```
a = (('_a_1', '_a_2'), [0.3, 0.6]) 
b = (('_a_3', '_a_4'), [0.15, 0.56]) 
c = (('_a_5', '_a_6'), [0.22, 0.6])

l = [[elem[0][-1],elem[1][-1]] for elem in list(zip(a,b,c))[0]]

print(l)
```

Output:

```
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with regex without splitting it :

```
import re
pattern=r'[0-9]+'

print([tuple(map(lambda x:re.search(pattern,x).group(),i[0])) for i in l])
```

output:

```
[('1', '2'), ('3', '4'), ('5', '6')]
```