# Python List Comprehensions -For all the numbers 1-1000, use a list comprehension to find the highest single digit any of the numbers is divisible by

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

This is my approach so far:

```
results = [for number in range(1,1001) max([divisor for divisor in range(1,10) if number % divisor == 0])]
```

Except I can't figure out why this doesn't work. All answers would be lovely, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding nested list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049798/understanding-nested-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which you use list comperhension is incorrect. Use

```
results = [max([divisor for divisor in range(1,10) if number % divisor == 0]) for number in range(1,1001) ]
```

The syntax is

```
[ expression for item in list if conditional ]
```

Source: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you! I knew I was close haha just couldn't figure out the last step.

Comment: If your problem is solved you should accept the answer :)