# Need to wrap code in single line with the use of comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

```
for s in strategies:
        strats_having_fcs = {a.strategy: a.algorithmType for a in s.algorithms if a.algorithmType == AlgorithmTypeEnum.feedback_control.value}
```

can we make it in single line by comprehension?

Comment: Why are you stomping over the value of `strats_having_fcs` every iteration?

Answer (score 2):

Just:

```
strats_having_fcs = {a.strategy: a.algorithmType for s in strategies for a in s.algorithms if a.algorithmType == AlgorithmTypeEnum.feedback_control.value}
```

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8049798/9041661) SO question about within-list comprehension. For me this clarified a lot how the logic behind this works.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, perhaps you are looking for this nested comprehension

```
strats_having_fcs = {a.strategy: a.algorithmType for s in strategies for a in s.algorithms 
                     if a.algorithmType == AlgorithmTypeEnum.feedback_control.value}
```

Comment: yeah, but it will give an error near to s.algorithms saying s is unresolved reference.