# Understanding python nested iteration inside a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am having a hard time interpreting nested iteration inside a list comprehension. Below code

```
movie = []
genre = []
for movie_ids in ratings["movie_id"].values:
  movie.append(movie_ids)
  genre.append([x for movie_id in movie_ids for x in genres_dict[movie_id]])
```

If I print `genre[0]` suppose I see a result `[a,b,c]`

My understanding from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049798/understanding-nested-list-comprehension) and many others on the internet was that I can replace the line

```
genre.append([x for movie_id in movie_ids for x in genres_dict[movie_id]])
```

With

```
for movie_id in movie_ids:
    if movie_id in genres_dict:
      genre.append(genres_dict[movie_id])
```

But that gives a different result when I print `genre[0]`

What am I missing?

Please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the list comprehension, you are also iterating over the contents of `genres_dict[movie_id]`. This code would not quite translate into the for loop you provided, but instead into

```py
for movie_id in movie_ids:
    for x in genres_dict[movie_id]
        genre.append(x)
```

I have omitted the `if` statement because, although it is not a bad idea to test whether the key exists, the nested iteration does not perform this test either. Nested iteration essentially performs the for loops you provide, nested, from the left to the right, and then appends the result of the expression.

Furthermore, appending the result of a list comprehension does not add every element of the list comprehension individually, but instead the entire list as one element. So the code actually performs

```py
list_out = []
for movie_id in movie_ids:
    for x in genres_dict[movie_id]
        list_out.append(x)
genre.append(list_out)
```

If you want to add all of the elements of the list comprehension, you should instead use `list.extend`, which takes an iterable as an argument and adds every element to the list. In your original code this would be
`genre.extend([x for movie_id in movie_ids for x in genres_dict[movie_id]])`.

Answer (score 0):

The list comprehension is actually flattening the array for you as it iterates over the inner content also.

The equivalent code block would be this. Notice the `extend` vs `append`.

```
for movie_id in movie_ids:
    if movie_id in genres_dict:
      genre.extend(genres_dict[movie_id])
```

The `extend` takes care of iterating over each item and adding it to the `genre` list. See docs for `append` vs `extend`.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html