# Undo python list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

This piece of python code is an example of list comprehension

```py
lst = [ x**2 for x in [x**2 for x in range(11)]]

# [0, 1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401, 4096, 6561, 10000]
```

How would this be written if it was not in list comprehension?

My understanding is that the list generated is the square of the square of each number in range(11). So I understand this is how to get the first part:

```py
lst = []
for item in range(11):
    lst.append(item**2)
print(lst)

# [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

But how can I get the second part?

Comment: You've done the first half, which is the inner list. What is left is to handle the rest, which is `lst = [x**2 for x in lst]`. You do it the same way.

Comment: Related: [Understanding nested list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049798/understanding-nested-list-comprehension)

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, could you please check this question as answered? Thank you

Comment: But ... why to not `x**4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = [ x**2 for x in [x**2 for x in range(11)]]

# equivalent to:
squares = []
squares2 = []
for x in range(11):
    squares.append(x**2)

for item in squares:
    squares2.append(item**2)
    
print(squares2)
print(squares2==lst)
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401, 4096, 6561, 10000]
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the loop twice

```py
lst = []
for item in range(11):
    lst.append(item**2)
i = 0
for item in lst:
    lst[i] = (item**2)
    i = i + 1
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

The comprehension is equivalent to

```
lst = []
for item in range(11):
    lst.append((item**2)**2)
```

after which you can

```
print(lst)
```

to observe

```
[0, 1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401, 4096, 6561, 10000]
```

Comment: The comprehension has the same result as this, but it does it differently, by executing two loops...

Comment: @zvone Which is both inefficient and redundant c:

Comment: But the question is about what the comprehension is doing, not how to make it better.

Comment: @zvone "How would this be written if it was not in list comprehension?" in my books means: "Show me equivalent code that does not use list comprehension." OP's initial code clearly shows how the elements of range(11) are mapped to x1 and then to x2, which is exactly what my code does.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as:

```
lst = []
num_lst = []
for x in range(11):
    num_lst.append(x**2)
for x in num_lst:
    lst.append(x**2)
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401, 4096, 6561, 10000]
```