# Simplified python list comprehension using for

Tags: python

i have following python list comprehension and it's hard for me to understand it

```
set([device for room, devices in home.items() for device in devices['devices'] + device_synonyms])
```

I need to simplified it using `for operator`

```
home = {'Гостиная': {'devices': ['Мак', 'Основной', 'Ночник']}, 'Коридор': {'devices': ['Роутер', 'Вход', 'Шкаф', 'Вешалка']}, 'Спальня': {'devices': ['Ночник']}}
```

The expected result should be

```
{'Вход', 'Ночник', 'Шкаф', 'Вешалка', 'Основной', 'Роутер', 'Мак'}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding nested list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049798/understanding-nested-list-comprehension)

Comment: Note: there is no need for this to be a list comprehension. You can feed a generator expression to `set`.

Comment: @Chris you mean something like set((device for room, devices in home.items() for device in devices['devices'] + device_synonyms))

Comment: Almost. You can elide a set of parentheses. `set(device for room, devices in home.items() for device in devices['devices'] + device_synonyms)`

Answer (score 2):

The exact translation of the listr comprehension to a for loop is given by:

```py
l = []
for room, devices in home.items():
   for device in devices["devices"] + device_synonyms:
       l.append(device)
s = set(l)
print(s)
```

As pointed out by chris, there is no need to use the intermediate list:

```py
s = set()
for room, devices in home.items():
   for device in devices["devices"] + device_synonyms:
       s.add(device)
print(s)
```

Comment: There's no need for the intermediate `l` list. You can create `s`, then add to it in the loop with `s.add(device)`.

Comment: That's true chris, thanks for the addition. I wanted to exactly replicate the comprehension line for demonstration purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `room` and you don't have to append `device_synonyms` multiple times as duplicates will be removed by `set()` anyway. So the code can be simplified and rewritten as:

```
result = set(device_synonyms)
for devices in home.values():
    result |= set(devices['devices'])
```